# Adding submit button to jquery star rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, rating

I have a default star rating system in my smarty template. it works great for desktop users but in mobile device, I found I always tap on the wrong value. I wish I could add a button to submit my rating instead of automatically submit when user tapping on star.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".one-star, .two-stars, .three-stars, .four-stars, .five-stars").click(function() {
                $("#current_rating").width($(this).html()*30);
                $.ajax({data: ({ action: 'save_rating', rating: $(this).html(), listing_id: <?php echo $id; ?>}), success: function() { window.location.href = '<?php echo $this->escape(URL); ?>'; }});
                return false;
            });
        });

            <ul class="star-rating">
                <li id="current_rating" class="current-rating" style="width:<?php echo $rating*30; ?>px;"><?php echo $rating; ?> Stars.</li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="1 star" class="one-star">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="2 stars" class="two-stars">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="3 stars" class="three-stars">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="4 stars" class="four-stars">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="5 stars" class="five-stars">5</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Do you want to have value in something like textbox to ensure the right value before submit?

Comment: Hi Adil, no need for textbox. at least user can reselect desired stars before hit the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this element to your html part:

```
<input type=button id=submit_rating value="submit rate" />
```

and change your jquery code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var rate=null;
        $(".one-star, .two-stars, .three-stars, .four-stars, .five-stars").click(function() {
             rate = $(this).html();
             $("#current_rating").width(rate*30);
        });
        $('#submit_rating').click(function(){
                $.ajax({data: ({ action: 'save_rating', rating: rate, listing_id: <?php echo $id; ?>}), success: function() { window.location.href = '<?php echo $this->escape(URL); ?>'; }});
                return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Falahat, There's no respond when I click on star

Comment: click on star then click on submit

Comment: hi again! the star does not respond when click it. you see it here http://mobiledirectory.my/dev/listing.php?id=1#

Comment: oh sorry i forget to write # in begin of 'submit_rating', i edited my answer, please replace this code with old one and check again ;)

Comment: thanks mohammad falahat it's works now! I'm in dilemma which solution to be use.. both yours and and jasper's is great! :)

Comment: @Pukau accept Mohammad's - he needs the rep to get basic privileges!

Answer (score 1):

How about using a dialog box to confirm the user's selection?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".one-star, .two-stars, .three-stars, .four-stars, .five-stars").click(function() {

            var currentrating = $(this).text()
            var r = confirm("Do you want to submit a rating of " + currentrating + "?") 

            if(r==true){ 

                 $("#current_rating").width($(this).html()*30);

                 $.ajax({data: ({ action: 'save_rating', rating: $(this).html(), listing_id: <?php echo $id; ?>}), success: function() { window.location.href = '<?php echo $this->escape(URL); ?>'; }});

                 return false;

            } else {

                 return false;

            }
        });
    });



        <ul class="star-rating">
            <li id="current_rating" class="current-rating" style="width:<?php echo $rating*30; ?>px;"><?php echo $rating; ?> Stars.</li>
                <li><a href="#" title="1 star" class="one-star">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="2 stars" class="two-stars">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="3 stars" class="three-stars">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="4 stars" class="four-stars">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="5 stars" class="five-stars">5</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Jasper!look promising! I'll try this method when I reached home